# JQuery - SlideToggle Multiple DIVs at the same time?

Tags: jquery, toggle, html, slidetoggle

I'm new at JQuery and I have a bit of an OCD issue.

I'm using SlideToggle with click function to hide/show a container div. However the div inside of it doesn't slide with it, it just appears.

Is there a way I can get both DIV's to slide in together?

JQUERY:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#store_container").hide();
  $('#toggle').click(function(){
     $('#store_container').slideToggle("slow"); 
     return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="store_container" style="display:none;">
    <div id="store_data">
        <p>THIS IS A TEST</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works for me (in webkit). Which browser are you using? Is this the exact code you're using? Is there some css with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#store_container").hide();
  $('#toggle').toggle(function(){
     $('#store_container').slideDown("slow", function() { $('#store_data').fadeIn(); });
   }, function() {
     $('#store_data').fadeOut("fast", function() { $('#store_container').slideUp("slow"); });
  });
});
</script>
  <div id="store_container" style="display:none; height: 300px;">
      <div id="store_data" style="display:none;">
        <p>THIS IS A TEST</p>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This didn't work and once the #store_container slid out, #store_data basically disappeared. Very odd.

Comment: This actually kept #store_data from disappearing..

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#store_container, #store_data').hide();
  $('#toggle').click(function(){
     $('#store_container, #store_data').slideToggle("slow"); 
     return false;
  });
});
</script>

But it still didn't let both DIVS slide down together, only one..

Comment: @iamtheratio - Updated, though your original sample works for me in FireFox....try my current answer.

Comment: @iamtheratio - Which browser are you using?  I'm seeing both slidedown with your original code here...need to see the effect you are.

Comment: @nick this works without error, but the odd part is once I click #toggle the #store_data instantly appears, then #store_container slides down.. Which is awful looking.

Comment: @iamtheratio - Try the above, a bit fancier, it'll slidedown (seems you have a specified height in your page, so you can use this) then fade in the inner contents after the slide...same reverse the other way.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm trying to figure this crap out, but I want everything to be perfect. haha.

Thanks again!